# count output of a function python

Tags: python, math, memory-management

I'm using the following code to test for prime numbers.

```
def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    yield [2] + [i for i in xrange(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]


outfile = open('primes','w')
input = input("Feed Me:")

outfile.write(str(primes(input)))
print "Done"
```

Is there a simple way of getting a count of the prime numbers generated.  As opposed to printing the actual numbers?
Also could this code be made to generate prime numbers above 100000000 without overflowing?

Comment: https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html

Comment: FWIW, your code only yields a single object (a list), so you should change that `yield` to `return`. The `yield` statement is used to make a generator; see [the docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for further info.

Comment: Yeah that happened while I was mucking around.  I changed some code and had to change it back. I then posted the dumb version.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop every even number from the table, just integer divide by `2` to store the odd numbers only. `sum` works with booleans mapping them to ints: `True` is 1 and `False` is 0; notice that this works even without `2` in table for n >= 2 because `1` is marked as a prime in the table ;)

```
def n_primes(n):
    """ Returns  the number of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * (n//2)
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5) + 1,2):
        if sieve[i//2]:
            sieve[i*i//2::i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)

    return sum(sieve)
```

or even better, count the primes encountered:

```
def n_primes(n):
    """ Returns  the number of primes < n (for n > 2)"""
    n_p = 1  # 2 is a prime
    sieve = [True] * (n//2)
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5) + 1,2):
        if sieve[i//2]:
            n_p += 1
            sieve[i*i//2::i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)

    return n_p
```

---

Notice, that your `sieve` function does not return a list but a generator, that yields the result, you probably wanted to write the original code as

```
def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)

    return [2] + [i for i in xrange(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]
```

or using my generator version:

```
def primes(n):
    """ Yields a sequence of primes < n """
    if n <= 2:
        return

    yield 2
    sieve = [True] * (n//2)
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5) + 1,2):
        if sieve[i//2]:
            yield i
            sieve[i*i//2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
```

In the case of the first, you can do `len(primes(n))` to get the number (though this is wasteful), for the second do `sum(1 for i in primes(n))`

---

As for generating prime numbers above `100000000`, the `sieve` table would spend `(4 * n / 2)` bytes on 32-bit processor and `8 * n / 2` on 64-bit processor, so your mileage might vary... One would want to use some kind of `bitarray` though one is not built-in in python.

Comment: Good so far, but I still get a memory error around the 1000000000 mark.  The number I'm ultimately going for is: 18446744073709551615

Comment: Good luck. 18446744073709551615 is 2^64 bits, to store the sieve you need 2^60 bytes, which incidentally is 1048576 TiB. With current hard disk prices it will cost about 35 million dollars to store this data.

Comment: Of course you can use a sieve that does not require ~O(N) of bits, but instead use computation to offset for the lack of space, now a Pritchard sieve could fit in RAM; if you are lucky enough to have a really fast system that can test millions of numbers in a second with that, you could expect your program to finish before year 2100. Better to buy a good UPS though.

Comment: I wasn't expecting a fast answer to my prime numbering madness.  But It's looking like I'm not going to get any insight at all with my tiny CPU here.  Does anybody know of a publicly accessible data on prime numbers that I can grep for numbers below 18446744073709551615?

Comment: It's occurred to me I should probably share a bit more about my ultimate objective.  I'm trying to determine if I can derive the ability to factor any number up to 2^64.  I was thinking the fastest way to do this would be to keep a table of primes handy, if possible.  Since I was reasonably sure the answer might be no.  I was looking to generate the table and then look at ways of cutting it down to size.

Comment: It is possible to also calculate the approximation of number of primes under `n` with the [π(x) approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), for example `x / ln x` gets within 1.7 % at 10^26

Comment: You can use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440674/4014959) I posted last year to find large primes in a range, eg `python range_sieve6.py 1234567890000 1234567890100` returns `[1234567890007L, 1234567890019L, 1234567890041L, 1234567890089L, 1234567890097L]` in 3.5 seconds on my 2GHz machine. But it won't be useful for investigating numbers of the **huge** size you're interested in.

Comment: "The value for π(10^24) was originally computed by J. Buethe, J. Franke, A. Jost, and T. Kleinjung assuming the Riemann hypothesis.[10] It has since been verified unconditionally in a computation by D. J. Platt.[11]", so the value of `π(2^64)` is known by now...

Comment: Using mpmath, π(18446744073709551615) is approximately  425656284014012122, computed using `mp.riemannr()`.  And `mp.primepi2()` returns the interval (4.2565627653473709e+17, 4.2565629169670016e+17).

Comment: @user34981: To factorize numbers < n² by trial division you can use a table of primes up to n. Eg, to factorize numbers up to 2^64 you'd use a table up to 2^32. That's not so bad - it's possible to store such a table with 30 numbers per byte (since all primes > 5 are of the form 30k±r with r in {1, 7, 11, 13}). FWIW, I have a database of primes up to 3000000000 here, so that's 100E6 bytes. However, performing those trial divisions for large numbers can take a _long_ time.

Comment: @user34981: Efficient factorization of large numbers requires fairly advanced mathematics. One popular algorithm is [Lenstra elliptic curve factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization). Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Current_state_of_the_art