# Finding the n largest primes under m

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, prime-factoring

The algorithm below is the Sieve of Eratosthenes which I have implemented in Python. This algorithm finds the first primes up to a given value, namely n.

The way this algorithm works is by printing all primes starting from 2 up to n. What I want to do is the other way around, that is, starting from n and going down to m, or some random slice e.g the largest 100 numbers. So for example.. if i had n being some huge number (e.g. 200 million), I would be able to print the largest 100 primes from 200 million (NOT FROM THE 200TH MILLION PRIME NUMBER, BUT A PRIME THAT IS EQUAL TO/LESS THAN 200 MILLION!).

Can anyone help?

```
def primes(n):    
    array = [i for i in range(2,n+1)] 
    p = 2 

    while p <= n:
        i = 2*p
        while i <= n:
            array[i-2] = 0
            i += p
        p += 1  

    return [num for num in array if num > 0]
```

Comment: how is it not working?

Comment: maybe you can set n to an upper limit based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem, but 100 million primes seems too many.

Comment: The code works, but I think I should be more specific, so sorry for any confusion. What I'm wondering is this: how can I build my primes in such a way that it works from n down to 2. So for example, if n = 100, I'd want it to print: 97, 89, 83, 73... etc

Comment: I updated it all, thanks @StefanPochmann and others

Comment: Since you don't always want to go "back to 2", that shouldn't be in the title. I suggest "Finding the n largest primes under m".

Comment: Thank you, all fixed. I am sorry for the question being very unclear.

Comment: It sounds like you need a [Range sieve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440674/4014959).

Comment: @PM2Ring But what's the range for let's say the largest 1000 primes less than 1000000?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Fair call. You can estimate the density of primes using the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), and from that compute an approximate lower number for the range to sieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
def largest_primes_under(number, cap):
    n = cap - 1
    while number and n >= 2:
        if all(n % d for d in range(2, int(n ** 0.5 + 1))):
            yield n
            number -= 1
        n -= 1
```

Demo:

```
for p in largest_primes_under(10, 10**9):
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
999999937
999999929
999999893
999999883
999999797
999999761
999999757
999999751
999999739
999999733
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand the code, what does this line mean:   if all(n % d for d in range(2, int(n ** 0.5 + 1)))? More specifically, where does int(n ** 0.5 + 1) come from?

Comment: @Shotokan That expression tests whether `n` leaves a remainder for all candidate divisors `d`, i.e., whether it's not divisible by any of them. And the `int(n ** 0.5 + 1)` is just the usual limit - there's no point in testing divisor candidates larger than the square root of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of the range sieve program I linked to in the comments. It uses the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) to get an approximation of the density of primes near `hi` and uses that density to estimate `lo` such that the number of primes in `range(lo, hi)` >= `num`. For further info please see the Mathworld article on the [Prime Counting Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html).

Generally, there's no simple way to accurately estimate the number of primes in a given range. FWIW, in special cases it's easy to show that there are no primes in a given range, eg every number in `range(n! + 2, n! + n + 1)` is clearly divisible by a number in `range(2, n + 1)`.

The code below (hopefully :) ) over-estimates the required range. But we don't want it to waste time by using a value for `lo` that's too low. In some cases, `lo` won't be small enough, especially when `num` is very small, but it should be ok if you use sensible values for `num`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Prime range sieve.

    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.15

    2015.05.24 Modified to find the `num` highest primes < `hi` 
'''

import sys
from math import log

def potential_primes():
    ''' Make a generator for 2, 3, 5, & thence all numbers coprime to 30 '''
    s = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29)
    for i in s:
        yield i
    s = (1,) + s[3:] 
    j = 30
    while True:
        for i in s:
            yield j + i
        j += 30


def range_sieve(lo, hi):
    ''' Create a list of all primes in the range(lo, hi) '''

    #Mark all numbers as prime
    primes = [True] * (hi - lo)

    #Eliminate 0 and 1, if necessary
    for i in range(lo, min(2, hi)):
        primes[i - lo] = False

    ihi = int(hi ** 0.5)
    for i in potential_primes():
        if i > ihi: 
            break

        #Find first multiple of i: i >= i*i and i >= lo
        ilo = max(i, 1 + (lo - 1) // i ) * i

        #Determine how many multiples of i >= ilo are in range
        n = 1 + (hi - ilo - 1) // i

        #Mark them as composite
        primes[ilo - lo : : i] = n * [False]

    return [i for i,v in enumerate(primes, lo) if v]


def main():
    hi = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 1000000
    num = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 1000

    #Estimate required range using the prime number theorem
    #The constant 1.25506 is from the MathWorld article on
    #the Prime Counting Function
    d = num * log(hi) * 1.25506

    #An alternate estimator. Sometimes estimates a little too low. 
    #d = num * (log(hi) + log(log(hi)))

    lo = max(2, hi - int(d))
    print 'lo =', lo

    primes = range_sieve(lo, hi)
    print len(primes), 'primes found'

    for i, p in enumerate(reversed(primes[-num:]), 1): print '%2d: %d' % (i, p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output** when called with `$ python range_sieve.py 1234567890 60`

```
lo = 1234566314
67 primes found
 1: 1234567811
 2: 1234567801
 3: 1234567799
 4: 1234567783
 5: 1234567759
 6: 1234567723
 7: 1234567717
 8: 1234567679
 9: 1234567669
10: 1234567583
11: 1234567571
12: 1234567553
13: 1234567517
14: 1234567469
15: 1234567361
16: 1234567337
17: 1234567309
18: 1234567303
19: 1234567291
20: 1234567289
21: 1234567267
22: 1234567261
23: 1234567249
24: 1234567223
25: 1234567181
26: 1234567171
27: 1234567151
28: 1234567129
29: 1234567097
30: 1234567093
31: 1234567069
32: 1234567063
33: 1234567007
34: 1234566997
35: 1234566959
36: 1234566953
37: 1234566947
38: 1234566899
39: 1234566887
40: 1234566863
41: 1234566769
42: 1234566761
43: 1234566737
44: 1234566713
45: 1234566691
46: 1234566677
47: 1234566643
48: 1234566601
49: 1234566581
50: 1234566559
51: 1234566547
52: 1234566533
53: 1234566527
54: 1234566521
55: 1234566499
56: 1234566497
57: 1234566491
58: 1234566481
59: 1234566479
60: 1234566467
```

Answer (score -1):

Didn't run the code. It should work, but change where it is needed. I just posted it to give you the intuition.

```
def primes(n):    
    array = [1 for i in range(0,n)]
    array[0] = 0
    array[1] = 0 
    p = 2 
    while p <= n:
        i = 2*p
        while i <= n:
            array[i] = 0
            i += p
        p += 1
        while (array[p] == 0):
            p += 1 
    result = [] 
    i = 0
    while i <= n:
        if array[i]==1:
            result.append(i)
        i += 1
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def primes(n):
    p = n/2
    return (n%i for i in range(2, p+1))

def test_primes(n, n_largest):
    ret = (k for k in range(n, 0, -1) if all(primes(k)))
    return [ret.next() for v in range(n_largest)]
```

usage

```
>>print test_primes(20, 2)
[17, 19]
```

to get the n largest number under

the function "primes" get the rest of the division of an element by all the element less than its middle part then "test_primes" test if all thoses rests are 0 or not. if all the rests are not 0 then this element is a prime number so we print it