# Fastest way to Factor (Prime-1)/2 for 64-bit Prime?

Tags: python, c++, prime-factoring, factoring

I'm trying to gather some statistics on prime numbers, among which is the distribution of factors for the number (prime-1)/2. I know there are general formulas for the size of factors of uniformly selected numbers, but I haven't seen anything about the distribution of factors of one less than a prime.

I've written a program to iterate through primes starting at the first prime after 2^63, and then factor the (prime - 1)/2 using trial division by all primes up to 2^32. However, this is extremely slow because that is a lot of primes (and a lot of memory) to iterate through. I store the primes as a single byte each (by storing the increment from one prime to the next). I also use a deterministic variant of the Miller-Rabin primality test for numbers up to 2^64, so I can easily detect when the remaining value (after a successful division) is prime.

I've experimented using a variant of pollard-rho and elliptic curve factorization, but it is hard to find the right balance of between trial division and switching to these more complicated methods. Also I'm not sure I've implemented them correctly, because sometimes they seem to take a very lone time to find a factor, and based on their asymptotic behavior, I'd expect them to be quite quick for such small numbers.

I have not found any information on factoring many numbers (vs just trying to factor one), but it seems like there should be some way to speed up the task by taking advantage of this.

Any suggestions, pointers to alternate approaches, or other guidance on this problem is greatly appreciated.

---

Edit:
The way I store the primes is by storing an 8-bit offset to the next prime, with the implicit first prime being 3. Thus, in my algorithms, I have a separate check for division by 2, then I start a loop:

```py
factorCounts = collections.Counter()
while N % 2 == 0:
    factorCounts[2] += 1
    N //= 2
pp = 3
for gg in smallPrimeGaps:
    if pp*pp > N:
        break
    if N % pp == 0:
        while N % pp == 0:
            factorCounts[pp] += 1
            N //= pp
    pp += gg
```

Also, I used a wheel sieve to calculate the primes for trial division, and I use an algorithm based on the remainder by several primes to get the next prime after the given starting point.

---

I use the following for testing if a given number is prime (porting code to c++ now):

```cpp
bool IsPrime(uint64_t n)
{
    if(n < 341531)
        return MillerRabinMulti(n, {9345883071009581737ull});
    else if(n < 1050535501)
        return MillerRabinMulti(n, {336781006125ull, 9639812373923155ull});
    else if(n < 350269456337)
        return MillerRabinMulti(n, {4230279247111683200ull, 14694767155120705706ull, 1664113952636775035ull});
    else if(n < 55245642489451)
        return MillerRabinMulti(n, {2ull, 141889084524735ull, 1199124725622454117, 11096072698276303650});
    else if(n < 7999252175582851)
        return MillerRabinMulti(n, {2ull, 4130806001517ull, 149795463772692060ull, 186635894390467037ull, 3967304179347715805ull});
    else if(n < 585226005592931977)
        return MillerRabinMulti(n, {2ull, 123635709730000ull, 9233062284813009ull, 43835965440333360ull, 761179012939631437ull, 1263739024124850375ull});
    else
        return MillerRabinMulti(n, {2ull, 325ull, 9375ull, 28178ull, 450775ull, 9780504ull, 1795265022ull});
}
```

Comment: Some code snippets would help....

Comment: There's a Python program [pyecm](https://github.com/martingkelly/pyecm) which uses elliptic curve to find big factors. Unfortunately, it's designed for use from the command line, not for importing into your own scripts (at, least the version I have is like that). As for factorising a range of numbers, you could use a modified [segmented sieve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440674/4014959). It may not help _much_, since it still has to divide by primes<2^32 to check 64 bit numbers, but I guess it's worth checking out.

Comment: is implementign divisibility rules worthwhile?

Comment: Oops. I just noticed that I made I minor blunder in my previous comment. The segmented sieve algorithm has to loop over primes<2^32, it doesn't do division to find primes (apart from a single one at the start of each inner loop), but I guess it does have to do division if you want to factorise. FWIW, all primes >30 can be written as 30n+r for r in {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29}, so numbers of the form (p-1)/2 can be written as 15n+r for r in {0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14}. Obviously when r is in {3,5,6,9} the number isn't prime.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a definitive answer, but I do have some observations and some suggestions.

There are about 2*10^17 primes between 2^63 and 2^64, so any program you write is going to run for a while.

Let's talk about a primality test for numbers in the range 2^63 to 2^64. Any general-purpose test will do more work than you need, so you can speed things up by writing a special-purpose test. I suggest strong-pseudoprime tests (as in Miller-Rabin) to bases 2 and 3. If either of those tests shows the number is composite, you're done. Otherwise, look up the number (binary search) in a table of strong-pseudoprimes to bases 2 and 3 (ask Google to find those tables for you). Two strong pseudoprime tests followed by a table lookup will certainly be faster than the deterministic Miller-Rabin test you are currently performing, which probably uses six or seven bases.

For factoring, trial division to 1000 followed by Brent-Rho until the product of the known prime factors exceeds the cube root of the number being factored ought to be fairly fast, a few milliseconds. Then, if the remaining cofactor is composite, it will necessarily have only two factors, so SQUFOF would be a good algorithm to split them, faster than the other methods because all the arithmetic is done with numbers less than the square root of the number being factored, which in your case means the factorization could be done using 32-bit arithmetic instead of 64-bit arithmetic, so it ought to be fast.

Instead of factoring and primality tests, a better method uses a variant of the Sieve of Eratosthenes to factor large blocks of numbers. That will still be slow, as there are 203 million sieving primes less than 2^32, and you will need to deal with the bookkeeping of a segmented sieve, but considering that you factor lots of numbers at once, it's probably the best approach to your task.

I have code for everything mentioned above at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com).

Comment: For prime testing, I use a deterministic miller-rabin with various bases depending on the magnitude on the number. For ex, for 64-bit numbers, bases 2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, 1795265022 (all mod the number), which is proven to have no pseudoprimes < 2^64.

Comment: So you use up to 7 bases, probably no less than 3 bases whatever the input, and you have to do comparisons to determine how many of the bases to perform. My approach uses 2 bases and a binary search, so it will be faster than yours, at the expense of space to store the table of pseudoprimes. I don't recall, but it's not particularly large. If you do 3 bases (2, 3 and 5) the table of pseudoprimes becomes trivially small, and my approach will still be faster than yours. Remember that you are not building a general-purpose primality tester; you are exploiting information about your input.

Comment: I use the following, which uses a different number of tests based on the number. Note that I need to identify 64-bit primes in my 'next_prime', and I find (p-1)/2 being prime is common also:

Comment: Re: "[...]about 2*10^17 primes[...]" I don't need to enumerate all the primes, but the more samples I have, the more accurate my result can be. Letting my python program run on 8 distinct cores for a few days, I was able to cover ~45 million primes in the range, which gave me a good starting point. Now I just want to refine the process so I can get many more much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I store primes for later:
(I'm going to assume you want the factors of the number, and not just a primality test).

Copied from my website http://chemicaldevelopment.us/programming/2016/10/03/PGS.html

I’m going to assume you know the binary number system for this part. If not, just think of 1 as a “yes” and 0 as a “no”.

So, there are plenty of algorithms to generate the first few primes. I use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to compute a list.

But, if we stored the primes as an array, like [2, 3, 5, 7] this would take up too much space. How much space exactly?

Well, 32 bit integers which can store up to 2^32 each take up 4 bytes because each byte is 8 bits, and 32 / 8 = 4

If we wanted to store each prime under 2,000,000,000, we would have to store over 98,000,000,000. This takes up more space, and is slower at runtime than a bitset, which is explained below.

This approach will take 98,000,000 integers of space (each is 32 bits, which is 4 bytes), and when we check at runtime, we will need to check every integer in the array until we find it, or we find a number that is greater than it.

For example, say I give you a small list of primes: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]. I ask you if 15 is prime. How do you tell me?

Well, you would go through the list and compare each to 15.

Is 2 = 15?

Is 3 = 15?

. . .

Is 17 = 15?

At this point, you can stop because you have passed where 15 would be, so you know it isn’t prime.

Now then, let’s say we use a list of bits to tell you if the number is prime. The list above would look like:

001101010001010001010

This starts at 0, and goes to 19

The 1s mean that the index is prime, so count from the left: 0, 1, 2

**001**101010001010001010

The last number in bold is 1, which indicates that 2 is prime.

In this case, if I asked you to check if 15 is prime, you don’t need to go through all the numbers in the list; All you need to do is skip to 0 . . . 15, and check that single bit.

And for memory usage, the first approach uses 98000000 integers, whereas this one can store 32 numbers in a single integer (using the list of 1s and 0s), so we would need
2000000000/32=62500000 integers.

So it uses about 60% as much memory as the first approach, and is much faster to use.

We store the array of integers from the second approach in a file, then read it back when you run.

This uses 250MB of ram to store data on the first 2000000000 primes.

You can further reduce this with wheel sieving (like what you did storing (prime-1)/2)

I'll go a little bit more into wheel sieve.

You got it right by storing (prime - 1)/2, and 2 being a special case.

You can extend this to **p#** (the product of the first **p** primes)

For example, you use **(1#)*k+1** for numbers **k**

You can also use the set of linear equations **(n#)*k+L**, where **L** is the set of primes less than **n#** and 1 excluding the first **n** primes.

So, you can also just store info for **6*k+1** and **6*k+5**, and even more than that, because **L={1, 2, 3, 5}{2, 3}**

These methods should give you an understanding of some the methods behind it.

You will need someway to implement this bitset, such as a list of 32 bit integers, or a string.

Look at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray for a possible abstraction

Comment: Storing primes using p=30n+r for r in {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29} can be nice because there are 8 numbers in that set, so you can store the primes in a range of 30 numbers using a single byte. Of course, doing the necessary bit-fiddling to save & load primes in this format isn't particularly fast in Python, but it's not too shabby in C.

Comment: There is also a very compact way to store primes - using diffs. It is known that maximum 64-bit gap (difference between two consecutive primes) is 1550, it means it is enough to store fixed sized diffs of 11 bits for all 64-bit primes. Maximal 32-bit gap is 336, it is 9 bits. This encoding is very compact and simple but allows to read primes only sequentially, without random access. If to insert at some points full-size 64-bit primes then it will allow amortized random access - jump to nearest full-size entry and then sequentially scan primes after that.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question you have! Decided to code my own full solution from scratch in C++.

I have 3 main math functions (and several non-math) in my code:

1. `GenPrimesSieve_Eratosthenes()` which is used to generate all 32-bit primes, there are total 203280221 ([see here](http://www.umopit.ru/CompLab/primes32eng.htm)) primes that are 32-bit. These primes are used in functions mentioned in 2) and 3). This function uses [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).
2. `PrimeSieve()` is used for sieving a range suggested by you starting from 2^63. This function sieves only prime numbers. Algorithm similar to Eratosthenes is used.
3. `FactorSieve()` is used to use sieve to factor every number in a range. Actually I factor only those that have `2 * n + 1` as prime, i.e. those from range sieved by PrimeSieve().

All 3 functions above do almost same kind of work:

1. They take some small 32-bit prime P and sieve a range through it. For that initial offset near range start is computed. It is the smallest offset after range start that is a multiple of P.
2. Then using For loop I iterate with step P over whole range.
3. For the case of Sieve of Eratosthenes and also PrimeSieve() I mark every P's number as composite. For the case of FactorSieve() I store P as prime factor inside each number where P hits in the range.
4. Sieve of Eratosthens and PrimeSieve() they both go through bit vector where composites are marked and every non-composite is stored into final answer vector (array).
5. PrimeSieve() doesn't have bit-vector of composites, but instead while sieving it collected into vector-of-vector, it collected all prime factors. Only 32-bit factors are collected through sieving. To compute remaining 64-bit prime factor (it can be only one at most), I multiply all prime factors and divide number itself by this product.
6. By theorem taken from Sieve of Eratosthenes it is known that it is enough to sieve by at most `P = Sqrt(N)`, which implies that in FactorSieve() for 64-bit numbers to find 64-bit prime factor it is enough to sieve through only 32-bit primes. Also for PrimeSieve() it is enough to sieve by only all 32-bit numbers to PROVE that 64-bit number is prime.

There are also several other functions, for example big one is `ProcessRange()` which call PrimeSieve() and FactorSieve() and then outputs generated primes P above 2^63 and factors of (P - 1) / 2, outputs them to file.

All config variables are located at start of .cpp file starting from the line where output file name `"output.txt"` is located.

Another big function is `Main()` which first computes all 32-bit primes using Sieve of Eratosthenes, and then using this primes it calls ProcessRange() which creates separate threads for each range using [std::async()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), thus it uses all CPU cores that you have, starting as many threads as there are hardware threads (usually number of cores multiplied by 2 due to hyper-threading technology), number of threads is computed using [std::thread::hardware_concurrency](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency).

Also [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) is used for synchronization of threads and data, and [std::this_thread::yield()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) for giving away time to other threads when current thread is iddle. [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now) is used to measure time. And [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is used as container for all numbers and primes.

Resulting primes and factors are outputted to `"output.txt"` file, and progress statistics is written to console using [std::cout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout).

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/MMfveoMMr)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <optional>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg: '" + std::string(msg) + "'."); }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#define COUT(code) { std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(g_cout_mux); std::cout << TimeUtcStr() << ": " code; std::cout << std::flush; }
#define LN { std::cout << "LN " << std::setw(5) << __LINE__ << "  " << __FUNCTION__ << "  " << __FILE__ << std::endl << std::flush; }

static std::recursive_mutex g_cout_mux;

using u8 = uint8_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;
using u64 = uint64_t;

static std::string const out_fname = "output.txt";
u64 constexpr
    out_file_buf_size = 16ULL << 20, // This much bytes is used for output file buffering
    base_range_bits = 63, // Start sieving from 2^base_range_bits + 2^small_range_bits * small_irange_start
    small_range_bits = 24, // Small range bits sieved in single thread, in this case [2^63 + 2^24 * 5, 2^63 + 2^24 * (5 + 1)).
    small_irange_start = 0; // Which small range index should start from, all previous ranges should be sieved already

static double TimeSec() {
    static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb)
        .count();
}

static size_t NThreads() {
    return std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
}

static std::string TimeUtcStr() {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto seconds_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
    auto fractional_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
        now.time_since_epoch() - seconds_since_epoch);
    std::time_t now_as_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::tm utc_tm = *std::gmtime(&now_as_time_t);
    char buffer[80];
    std::strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S", &utc_tm);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << buffer << '.' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << fractional_seconds.count() / 1000;
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> GenPrimesSieve_Eratosthenes(uint64_t const end) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
    if (end <= 2)
        return {};
    uint64_t const cnt = end >> 1;
    std::vector<uint8_t> composites((cnt + 7) / 8);
    auto Get = [&](uint64_t const i){
        return bool((composites[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1);
    };
    auto Set = [&](uint64_t const i){
        composites[i / 8] |= uint8_t(1) << (i % 8);
    };
    std::vector<T> primes = {2};
    uint64_t i = 0, ops = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < cnt; ++i) {
        if (Get(i))
            continue;
        uint64_t const
            p = 2 * i + 1,
            start = (p * p) >> 1;
        primes.push_back(p);
        if (start >= cnt)
            break;
        for (uint64_t j = start; j < cnt; j += p)
            Set(j);
    }
    for (i = i + 1; i < cnt; ++i)
        if (!Get(i))
            primes.push_back(2 * i + 1);
    primes.shrink_to_fit();
    return primes;
}

static std::vector<u64> PrimeSieve(u64 begin, u64 end, std::vector<u32> const & small_primes) {
    if (begin % 2 == 0) ++begin;
    if (end % 2 == 1) --end;
    if (end <= begin) return {};
    
    u64 const cnt = (end - begin + 1) >> 1;
    std::vector<uint8_t> composites((cnt + 7) / 8); composites.shrink_to_fit();
    auto Get = [&](u64 i){ return bool((composites[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1); };
    auto Set = [&](u64 i){ composites[i / 8] |= u8(1) << (i % 8); };
    
    for (u64 const p: small_primes) {
        u64 const
            t = begin - begin % (p * 2) + p,
            start = t < begin ? t + p * 2 : t;
        for (u64 i = (start - begin) >> 1; i < cnt; i += p)
            Set(i);
        if (u64(p) * p >= end) {
            ASSERT_MSG(p < small_primes.back(),
                "To few small primes! Increase Eratosthenes sieving range.");
            break;
        }
    }
    
    std::vector<u64> primes;
    for (u64 i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
        if (!Get(i))
            primes.push_back(begin + i * 2);
    primes.shrink_to_fit();
    
    return primes;
}

static auto FactorSieve(u64 const begin, u64 const end, std::vector<u32> const & small_primes,
        u64 const fbegin, std::vector<bool> const & filter) {
    std::vector<std::vector<u32>> lo_factors(end - begin); lo_factors.shrink_to_fit();
    std::vector<std::optional<u64>> hi_factors(end - begin); hi_factors.shrink_to_fit();
    std::vector<u64> prods(end - begin, 1); prods.shrink_to_fit();
    
    for (auto const p: small_primes) {
        u64 mp = p;
        while (true) {
            u64 const
                t = begin - begin % mp,
                start = t < begin ? t + mp : t;
            if (start >= t && end + mp >= end) // Check add-overflow
                for (u64 i = start; i < end; i += mp)
                    if (filter[i * 2 + 1 - fbegin]) {
                        lo_factors[i - begin].push_back(p);
                        prods[i - begin] *= p;
                    }
            if ((mp * p) / p != mp)
                break;
            mp *= p;
        }
        if (u64(p) * p >= end) {
            ASSERT_MSG(p < small_primes.back(),
                "To few small primes! Increase Eratosthenes sieving range.");
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (u64 i = begin; i < end; ++i)
        if (filter[i * 2 + 1 - fbegin]) {
            std::sort(lo_factors[i - begin].begin(), lo_factors[i - begin].end());
            lo_factors[i - begin].shrink_to_fit();
        }
    
    for (u64 i = begin; i < end; ++i)
        if (filter[i * 2 + 1 - fbegin] && prods[i - begin] < i) {
            u64 const f = i / prods[i - begin];
            ASSERT(f * prods[i - begin] == i);
            hi_factors[i - begin] = f;
        }
    
    return std::make_pair(std::move(lo_factors), std::move(hi_factors));
}

static std::atomic<u64> cnt_outputted_ranges = small_irange_start;
static std::mutex output_mutex;

static void ProcessRange(size_t const base_bits, size_t const range_bits,
        u64 const irange, std::vector<u32> const & small_primes) {
    u64 const
        begin = (1ULL << base_bits) + (irange + 0) * (1ULL << range_bits),
        end   = (1ULL << base_bits) + (irange + 1) * (1ULL << range_bits);
    
    auto time_primes = TimeSec();
    auto const ps = PrimeSieve(begin, end, small_primes);
    time_primes = TimeSec() - time_primes;
    
    std::vector<bool> filter(end - begin);
    for (auto p: ps)
        filter.at(p - begin) = true;
    filter.shrink_to_fit();
    u64 const hbegin = begin / 2,
        hend = ((end - 1) / 2 * 2 + 1 > end - 1 ? (end - 2) / 2 : (end - 1) / 2) + 1;
    
    auto time_factor = TimeSec();
    auto const [flo, fhi] = FactorSieve(hbegin, hend, small_primes, begin, filter);
    time_factor = TimeSec() - time_factor;
    
    u64 mem_used = ps.capacity() * sizeof(ps[0]) + filter.capacity() * 1 +
        flo.capacity() * sizeof(flo[0]) + fhi.capacity() * sizeof(fhi[0]);
    for (u64 i = 0; i < flo.size(); ++i)
        mem_used += flo[i].capacity() * sizeof(flo[i][0]);
    
    std::ostringstream file;
    
    u64 hprimes_cnt = 0;
    for (u64 i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
        if (!filter.at(i - begin))
            continue; 
        u64 const q = (i - 1) / 2;
        file << "Range [2^" << base_bits << " + 2^" << range_bits << " * " << irange
            << ", 2^" << base_bits << " + 2^" << range_bits << " * " << (irange + 1)
            << "), prime p = " << i << ", factors of (p - 1) / 2 = " << q << ": ";
        u64 prod = 1;
        auto const & v = flo.at(q - hbegin);
        auto const & h = fhi.at(q - hbegin);
        size_t c = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
            ++c;
            prod *= v[j];
            file << v[j] << (j + 1 >= v.size() && !h ? "" : ", ");
        }
        if (h) {
            ++c;
            prod *= *h;
            file << *h;
        }
        file << std::endl;
        if (c == 1)
            ++hprimes_cnt;
        ASSERT_MSG(prod == q, "For p = " + std::to_string(i) + " error in factoring (p - 1) / 2 = " +
                std::to_string(q) + ", product of factors " + std::to_string(prod) + ", factors: " + [&]{
            std::ostringstream ss;
            for (auto e: v)
                ss << e << ", ";
            if (h)
                ss << *h;
            return ss.str();
        }());
        ASSERT(c > 0);
    }
    
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> file_lock(output_mutex);
        
        if (irange > cnt_outputted_ranges) {
            file_lock.unlock();
            std::this_thread::yield();
        } else {
            ASSERT_MSG(irange == cnt_outputted_ranges, "irange " + std::to_string(irange) +
                ", cnt_outputted_ranges " + std::to_string(cnt_outputted_ranges));
            std::ofstream ofile(out_fname, std::ios::app);
            ASSERT_MSG(ofile.is_open(), "Can't open file '" + out_fname + "' for write-append!");
            //ofile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, out_file_buf_size);
            ofile << file.str();
            ofile.close();
            ASSERT_MSG(ofile.good(), "Error closing file '" + out_fname + "'!");
            cnt_outputted_ranges = irange + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    COUT(<< "Processed range [2^" << base_bits << " + 2^" << range_bits << " * " << std::setw(3) << irange
        << ", 2^" << base_bits << " + 2^" << range_bits << " * " << std::setw(3) << (irange + 1)
        << "), prime sieve time " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(4) << time_primes
        << " sec, count primes " << ps.size() << ", half factor sieve time " << std::setw(4) << time_factor
        << " sec, count half primes (Sophie Germain) " << hprimes_cnt << ", range mem usage "
        << 1.0 * mem_used / (1 << 20) << " MiB" << std::endl);
}

static void Main() {
    COUT(<< "Creating table of all 32-bit primes! Wait around 1-2 minutes..." << std::endl);
    auto const small_primes = GenPrimesSieve_Eratosthenes<u32>(u32(-1));
    // http://www.umopit.ru/CompLab/primes32eng.htm
    // In total there are 203280221 primes that are 32-bit in size.
    ASSERT_MSG(small_primes.size() == 203280221,
        "small_primes.size() " + std::to_string(small_primes.size()));
    COUT(<< "Small primes count " << small_primes.size()
        << " and mem usage " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1)
        << 1.0 * small_primes.capacity() * sizeof(small_primes[0]) / (1 << 20)
        << " MiB" << std::endl);
    // Erase file if starting from 0 range
    if (small_irange_start == 0) {
        COUT(<< "Erasing output file!" << std::endl);
        std::ofstream out_cleanup(out_fname);
        ASSERT(out_cleanup.is_open());
    }
    COUT(<< "Starting ranges processing from range index " << small_irange_start << std::endl);
    
    std::vector<std::future<void>> asyncs;
    for (u64 irange = small_irange_start;; ++irange) {
        while (asyncs.size() >= NThreads()) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < asyncs.size(); ++j)
                if (asyncs[j].wait_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1)) == std::future_status::ready) {
                    asyncs[j].get();
                    asyncs.erase(asyncs.begin() + j);
                    break;
                }
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
        asyncs.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&, irange]{
            ProcessRange(base_range_bits, small_range_bits, irange, small_primes);
        }));
    }
    
    COUT(<< ": All done!" << std::endl);
}

int main() {
    try {
        Main();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        COUT(<< "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
2024.03.22 12:23:12.300: Creating table of all 32-bit primes! Wait around 1-2 minutes...
2024.03.22 12:27:09.031: Small primes count 203280221 and mem usage 775.5 MiB
2024.03.22 12:27:09.071: Erasing output file!
2024.03.22 12:27:09.076: Starting ranges processing from range index 0
2024.03.22 12:27:42.648: Processed range [2^63 + 2^24 *   0, 2^63 + 2^24 *   1),
    prime sieve time  6.4 sec, count primes 192022, half factor sieve time 13.4 sec,
    count half primes (Sophie Germain) 5871, range mem usage 340.0 MiB
2024.03.22 12:27:44.486: Processed range [2^63 + 2^24 *   1, 2^63 + 2^24 *   2),
    prime sieve time  6.5 sec, count primes 192350, half factor sieve time 13.1 sec,
    count half primes (Sophie Germain) 6014, range mem usage 340.0 MiB
```

File `output.txt`:

```
Range [2^63 + 2^24 * 0, 2^63 + 2^24 * 1), prime p = 9223372036854775907, factors of
    (p - 1) / 2 = 4611686018427387953: 113, 149, 273901883852669
Range [2^63 + 2^24 * 0, 2^63 + 2^24 * 1), prime p = 9223372036854775931, factors of
    (p - 1) / 2 = 4611686018427387965: 5, 13, 13, 13, 4073, 103073081453
Range [2^63 + 2^24 * 0, 2^63 + 2^24 * 1), prime p = 9223372036854775939, factors of
    (p - 1) / 2 = 4611686018427387969: 3, 43, 2389, 16823, 889509163
Range [2^63 + 2^24 * 0, 2^63 + 2^24 * 1), prime p = 9223372036854775963, factors of
    (p - 1) / 2 = 4611686018427387981: 3, 3, 15139, 33846988414231
```