# How to speed up Sieve of Eratosthenes python list generator

Tags: python, list, computer-science

My problem comes directly from the CS circles site. It's the last problem on the bottom of [this](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/18-efficiency/) page called 'Primed for Takeoff'. The basic rundown is they want a list of 1,000,001 length, where the index of each item is True if the index is prime, while the index of each item is False if it is not prime.

So, for example, isPrime[13] is True. isPrime[14] is False.

The first little bit of the list 'isPrime' would look like:

```
isPrime = [False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, ...]
```

My problem is the 7-second time limit they have. I have a working code below with a lower number, 101, for debugging purposes. When I bump it up to their required 1,000,001 list length, it takes way too long, I ended up killing the program after a few minutes.
This is my working (at length 101), very slow code:

```
n = 101
c = 2
isPrime = [False,False]
for i in range(2,n):
    isPrime.append(i)

def ifInt(isPrime):
    for item in isPrime:
        if type(item) == int:
            return item
for d in range(2,n):
    if c != None:
        for i in range(c,n,c):
            isPrime[i] = False
        isPrime[c] = True
        c = ifInt(isPrime)
```

Then there's this one I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python). It has a quicker run time, but only outputs a list of primes, not a list of n length with list[n] returning True for primes and false otherwise.

I'm not sure if this 2nd bit of code really holds the key to creating a prime list of length 1,000,001 in under 7 seconds, but it was the most relevant thing I could find in my research.

```
def primes_sieve1(limit):
    limitn = limit+1
    primes = dict()
    for i in range(2, limitn): primes[i] = True

    for i in primes:
        factors = range(i,limitn, i)
        for f in factors[1:]:
            primes[f] = False
    return [i for i in primes if primes[i]==True]
```

CS circles seems pretty commonly used, but I wasn't able to find a working version of this for Python. Hopefully this will be an easy solve for someone.

This question differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) because am not trying to only create a list of primes quickly, but to create a list of all positive integers from 0 to n that are marked as prime by True and non prime by False.

Comment: The answer in the code you linked actually generates that exact array in well under 7 seconds. You should try to understand what that very short snippet of code does.

Comment: `return [i for i in primes if primes[i]==True]`

This line filter only list of prime numbers when index i is prime. Hope this hint is helpful to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n

Comment: Note that listing primes is entirely equivalent to the True/False array you have described, and likely any program that lists primes only requires very minor changes to get the boolean array.

Comment: I'm suggesting taking one of those solutions and making some very minor modifications (index access for example instead of appending) to get what you want.

Comment: I made n 101 instead of 1000001 in the snippet I provided. At 1000001 it does not run in under 7 seconds. @pvg

Comment: @Untitled123 good idea. Thanks!

Comment: @adhdj The code in the answer you linked, including printing, like so `print list(sieve.primes_sieve2(10000000))` runs under 7 seconds. It's 10 times the size of your problem and generates the list in question internally. All you have to do is take it out.

Comment: Right. I'll play around with it, but my problem isn't getting a list of primes in under 7 seconds, it's getting that list to be in the format mentioned above in under 7 seconds. I think I'm on the right path though. @pvg

Comment: @adhdj, I guess what we're getting at is that the solution where you get all primes is entirely equivalent to getting the list above. In fact, I would imagine getting your list should be faster than getting the list of all primes. Current code below gets the answer in under a tenth of a second. (0.05 s on my computer). Read through some of the optimizations and  try to incorporate them into your solution. At a cursory scan, your isInt method is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @adhdj I'm not sure how I can repeat this in any clearer way. The answer you linked _produces the list in question_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I realized that there a lot of optimizations on SO, but they are rarely ever explained by others for the prime sieve algorithm, so it makes them difficult to approach by beginners or first time creators of the algorithm. All the solutions here are in python, to be on the same page for speed and optimizations. These solutions will progressively become faster and more complex. :)

### Vanilla Solution

```
def primesVanilla(n):
    r = [True] * n
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    for i in xrange(n):
        if r[i]:
            for j in xrange(i+i, n, i):
                r[j] = False
    return r
```

This is a very straightforward implementation of the Sieve. Please make sure you understand what is going on above before proceeding. The only slight thing to note is that you start marking not-primes at i+i instead of i, but this is rather obvious. (Since you assume that i itself is a prime). To make tests fair, all numbers will be for the list up to **25 million**.

```
real    0m7.663s  
user    0m7.624s  
sys     0m0.036s
```

### Minor Improvement 1 (Square roots):

I'll try to sort them in terms of straight-forward to less straight-forward changes. Observe that we do not need to iterate to n, but rather only need to go up to the square root of n. The reason being that any composite number under n, must have a prime factor under or equal to the square root of n. When you sieve by hand, you'll notice that all the "unsieved" numbers over the square root of n are by default primes.

Another remark is that you have to be a little bit careful for when the square root turns out to be an integer, so you should add one in this case so it covers it. IE, at n=49, you want to loop until 7 inclusive, or you might conclude that 49 is prime.

```
def primes1(n):
    r = [True] * n
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    for i in xrange(int(n**0.5+1)):
        if r[i]:
            for j in xrange(i+i, n, i):
                r[j] = False
    return r

real    0m4.615s
user    0m4.572s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Note that it's quite a bit faster. When you think about it, you're looping only until the square root, so what would take 25 million top level iterations now is only 5000 top level.

### Minor Improvement 2 (Skipping in inner loop):

Observe that in the inner loop, instead of starting from i+i, we can start from i*i. This follows from a very similar argument to the square root thing, but the big idea is that any composites between i and i*i have already been marked by smaller primes.

```
def primes2(n):
    r = [True] * n
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    for i in xrange(int(n**0.5+1)):
        if r[i]:
            for j in xrange(i*i, n, i):
                r[j]=False
    return r

real    0m4.559s
user    0m4.500s
sys     0m0.056s
```

Well that's a bit disappointing. But hey, it's still faster.

### Somewhat Major Improvement 3 (Even skips):

The idea here is that we can premark all the even indices, and then skip iterations by 2 in the main loop. After that we can start the outer loop at 3, and the inner loop can skip by 2*i instead. (Since going by i instead implies that it'll be even, (i+i) (i+i+i+i) etc.)

```
def primes3(n):
    r = [True] * n
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    for i in xrange(4,n,2):
        r[i] = False    
    for i in xrange(3, int(n**0.5+1), 2):
        if r[i]:
            for j in xrange(i*i, n, 2*i):
                r[j] = False
    return r

real    0m2.916s
user    0m2.872s
sys     0m0.040s
```

### Cool Improvements 4 (wim's idea):

This solution is a rather advanced trick. Slice assignment is faster than looping, so this uses python's slice notation: `r[begin:end:skip]`

```
def primes4(n):
    r = [True] * n
    r[0] = r[1] = False 
    r[4::2] = [False] * len(r[4::2])
    for i in xrange(3, int(1 + n**0.5), 2):
        if r[i]:
            r[i*i::2*i] = [False] * len(r[i*i::2*i])
    return r

10 loops, best of 3: 1.1 sec per loop
```

### Slight Improvement 5

Note that python reslices the `r[4::2]` when it calculates the length, so this takes quite a bit of extra time since all we need for it is computing the length. We do use some nasty math to achieve this though.

```
def primes5(n):
    r = [True] * n
    r[0] = r[1] = False 
    r[4::2] = [False] * ((n+1)/2-2)
    for i in xrange(3, int(1 + n**0.5), 2):
        if r[i]:
            r[i*i::2*i] = [False] * ((n+2*i-1-i*i)/(2*i))
    return r

10 loops, best of 3: 767 msec per loop
```

### Assignment speed-up (Padraic Cunningham):

Note that we assign an array with all True and then set half (the evens) to be False. We can actually just start with a boolean array that's alternating.

```
def primes6(n):
    r = [False, True] * (n//2) + [True]
    r[1], r[2] = False, True
    for i in xrange(3, int(1 + n**0.5), 2):
        if r[i]:
            r[i*i::2*i] = [False] * ((n+2*i-1-i*i)/(2*i))
    return r

10 loops, best of 3: 717 msec per loop
```

Don't quote me on this, but I think without some nasty math methods, there is no obvious improvements to this last version. One cute property that I tried, but did not turn out to be any faster is noting that primes other than 2,3 must be of the form 6k+1 or 6k-1. (Note that if it's 6k, then divisible by 6, 6k+2 | 2, 6k+3 | 3, 6k+ 4 | 2, 6k+5 is congruent to -1 mod 6. This suggests that we can skip by 6 each time and check both sides. Either from a poor implementation on my side, or python internals, I was unable to find any meaningful speed increase. :(

Comment: ＋1  nice.  It's always been my opinion that list slices in python should have been views, not copies.  I was sad that this wasn't done in python3.

Comment: Creating a slice just to find its length is rather wasteful of time & RAM when it's easy enough to calculate the correct length. See my [boolean prime sieve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26193172/4014959)

Comment: @PM2Ring, I absolutely agree. Would you be able to figure out what the length of the len(r[i*i::2*i]) should be? I wasn't able to do the calculation correct yesterday :(

Comment: Also, note that I skip a bit more than your algorithm, so the calculate is a bit different.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, had a complete overhaul, had some embarrassing mistakes in previous code. Everything should now be working under python 2.7.9.

Comment: I still get `ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 49999 to extended slice of size 49998`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what number did you use to put in?

Comment: didn't get any issues for 
for x in xrange(100,1000000,178):
    primes5(x)

Comment: You may want to change those `/` to `//` to enforce integer division in Python 3.

Comment: The xrange is also a relic of Python 2.7, my brain is telling me to move to 3, but my heart is telling me no

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I saw is the way you generate the initial list (looping and appending) is inefficient and unnecessary.  You can just *add* lists instead of looping and appending per-element.

The second thing I saw is that the type-checking you are doing is unnecessary, that function call is expensive and you can refactor to avoid that completely.

Finally, I think the "big thing" you can get in any sieve implementation is taking advantage of a slice assignment.  You should cross out all the factors in one hit instead of looping.  Example:

```
from math import sqrt

def primes(n):
    r = [True] * n
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    r[4::2] = [False] * len(r[4::2])
    for i in xrange(int(1 + sqrt(n))):
        if r[i]:
            r[3*i::2*i] = [False] * len(r[3*i::2*i])
    return r
```

Note I also have a couple of other tricks:

- avoid half of the work by crossing out even numbers immediately.
- only iterating up to sqrt of the length is necessary

On my crappy underpowered macbook this code can generate the 1,000,001 list in about 75 milliseconds:

```
>>> timeit primes(1000001)
10 loops, best of 3: 75.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think you should use `range` instead of `enumerate` since that makes a copy of the list.

Comment: Well enumerate doesn't but slicing does.

Comment: Ahh, got it.  Good idea I'll fix it.

Comment: I don't think the even cross saves any work, considering that's what happens when you run it on 2 normally anyways. It's phrased deceptively currently? There's also already very good answers for crazily fast prime sieves and neat optimizations..why not link to one?

Comment: Because I think some of the crazily fast ones obscure the quite simple idea of how the sieving works.  This is fast enough, but readable and easily understandable what's going on.

Comment: Hm, perhaps it's an opinion thing, but I'd say that             r[3*i::2*i] = [False] * len(r[3*i::2*i])
is not great for readability (nor is it any fast I think) if we're talking vanilla sieves.

Comment: And you are misunderstanding where the "work" in the even cross disappears from - it means we can step by 2*i **inside the loop** instead of stepping by i.

Comment: If you can beat this on efficiency yet maintain the simplicity I will be very interested to see  :)

Comment: Hm, read that but didn't connect it to the work haha! While this answer gets the job done, perhaps I'm just picky of where it's in terms of optimization. Namely that there are some optimizations, but still missing some other common ones (such as starting from 3*i instead of i*i), and not adequately explaining the reasoning/optimizations that are being performed.

Comment: Posted slightly faster modification. List slicing assignment was totally foreign to me as being faster, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @Untitled123: Slice assignment is fast because it's performed at C speed, rather than assigning elements one by one at Python interpreter speed like you'd do with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Some timings show in python2 and 3 wim's approach is significantly faster, it can be slightly optimised further by how the list is created:

```
def primes_wim_opt(n):
    r = [False, True] * (n // 2)
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    r[2] = True
    for i in xrange(int(1 + n ** .5)):
        if r[i]:
            r[3*i::2*i] = [False] * len(r[3*i::2*i])
    return r
```

Python2 timings:

```
In [9]: timeit primesVanilla(100000)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.7 ms per loop

In [10]: timeit primes_wim(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.59 ms per loop

In [11]: timeit primes1(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop

In [12]: timeit primes_wim_opt(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.18 ms per loop

In [13]: timeit primes2(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop

In [14]: primes_wim(100000) ==  primes_wim_opt(100000) ==  primes(100000) == primesVanilla(100000) == primes2(100000)
Out[14]: True
```

Timings for python3 where using the same functions just changing to range:

```
In [76]: timeit primesVanilla(100000)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.3 ms per loop

In [77]: timeit primes_wim(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.92 ms per loop

In [78]: timeit primes1(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

In [79]: timeit primes_wim_opt(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 ms per loop

In [80]: timeit primes2(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop
In [81]: primes_wim(100000) ==  primes_wim_opt(100000) ==  primes(100000) == primesVanilla(100000) == primes2(100000)
Out[80]: True
```

it can be optimised further by instead using the len of range/xrange instead of slicing:

```
def primes_wim_opt(n):
    is_odd = n % 2 & 1    
    r = [False, True] * (n // 2 + is_odd)
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    r[2] = True
    for i in range(int(1 + n ** .5)):
        if r[i]:
            r[3*i::2*i] = [False] * len(range(3*i,len(r), 2 * i))
    return r
```

Python3 it knocks a good chunk  off:

```
In [16]: timeit primes_wim_opt_2(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 ms per loop
```

And the same for python2 using xrange:

```
In [10]: timeit  primes_wim_opt_2(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.60 ms per loop
```

Using `(((n - 3 * i) // (2 * i)) + 1)` should also work:

```
def primes_wim_opt_2(n):
    is_odd = n % 2 & 1
    r = [False, True] * ((n // 2) + is_odd)
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    r[2] = True
    for i in range(int(1 + n ** .5)):
        if r[i]:
            r[3*i::2*i] = [False] * (((n - 3 * i) // (2 * i)) + 1)
    return r
```

Which is very slightly faster:

```
In [12]: timeit primes_wim_opt_2(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop

In [6]: timeit primes5(100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.47 ms per loop
```

You can also start at 3 and step  2:

```
def primes_wim_opt_2(n):
    r = [False, True] * (n // 2)
    r[0] = r[1] = False
    r[2] = True
    for i in range(3, int(1 + n ** .5),2):
        if r[i]:
            r[3*i::2*i] = [False] * (((n - 3 * i) // (2 * i)) + 1)
    return r
```

Which is faster again:

```
In [2]: timeit primes_wim_opt_2(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.10 ms per loop
```

Python2:

```
In [2]: timeit primes_wim_opt_2(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop
```

Comment: You also fell victim to the calculations :) , slice length issues for 1000001

Comment: would you mind if I added the [False,True] trick to my answer? Speed up by 10% :)

Comment: "using the len of range/xrange instead of slicing" <-- a neat idea.  much less error prone than using the big pre-calculated fraction.