# python code giving wrong output

Tags: python

I have written the below code in python to print out prime numbers but its giving output like:

```
3,5,7,**9**,11,13,**15**,17,19,**21**,23,25............99
```

below is the code:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

def primes(n = 1):
    while(True):
        if isprime(n): yield n
        n += 1
for n in primes():
    if n > 100: break
    print(n)
```

Comment: What is the question? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @starf:  I think it's pretty clear.  The list of primes contains numbers that are not primes.  Rahul was expecting prime numbers only.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning `True` after the number fails to be divisible by *one* number. You need to return true after you have checked *all* the numbers. Instead, you should write

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

One other note: if you are testing for prime numbers, you only need to test up to **the square root of the number**. If the number is not divisible by any numbers less than its square root, then it is also is not divisible by any that are greater and thus must be prime. This will help make your code more efficient.

Comment: Also, it's worthwhile to treat `n == 2` as a special case and then only test for odd factors in the loop.

Comment: Indeed. Also, something like a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) would best for finding all primes below a given value.

Comment: [Definitely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26193172/4014959)! Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440674/4014959) for primes in a given range. For a comparison of various prime sieving algorithms in Python, see [Fastest way to list all primes below N](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440674/4014959). And for testing individual large numbers for primality there's [Miller-Rabin](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1638487/207316)... but that might be a getting a bit too advanced for the OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `isprime` function says:

```
for x in range(2, n):
    if n % x == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This means that on the *first iteration* (when `x==2`), if `n%x` is not zero, it will return True. So it will return True for any odd number (above 1, which you skipped).

Instead, you want to return True if *none* of the numbers in the loop were factors.

```
for x in range(2, n):
    if n % x == 0:
        return False
# the loop finished without returning false, so none of the numbers was a factor
return True
```