# How can I speed up my python program?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to make a program in Python 3.4.1 to obtain the prime numbers from 2 to 100,000.

My problem is that it takes too much time to process all the information and it never give me any result.

I had left it for around half an hour, it slows me all the computer and it doesn't give me what I want.

I am using the Eratosthenes' Sieve algorithm ["Criba de Eratostenes"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes).

Here is my code:

```
from math import *

def primos(num):
    num2     = num + 1
    tnumeros = []                      # tnumeros  = every number from 2 to num
    npnumeros= []                      # npnumeros = every number that is no prime
    pnumeros = []                      # pnumeros  = every prime number

    for a in range( 2, num2 ):
        tnumeros.append( a )

    for i in range( 2, int( sqrt( num ) ) + 1 ):
        for j in range( i, int( num / i ) + 1 ):
            np = i * j
            npnumeros.append( np )

    npnumeros = list( set( npnumeros ) )

    for e in tnumeros:
        if ( e in npnumeros ):
            continue
        else:
            pnumeros.append( e )

    return ( str( "".join( str( pnumeros ) ) ) )

print( primos( 100000 ) )
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is bug free. Code reviews can be asked on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or, you could argue that it has a performance bug, so fails its spec?

Comment: This isn't really the Sieve of Eratosthenes:  that algorithm identifies primes and removes multiples of each successive prime at the same time.  Here you're removing multiples for *every* integer, rather than just multiples of primes.

Comment: @matsjoyce: didn't you know, "runs slow" is not a bug, it's a *feature*!

Comment: @Jongware: I see the wrong implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes. It is not bug free. Here's [how the correct implementation of `sieve_of_eratosthenes(limit)` might look like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20782064/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a list for your `npnumeros` value; use a set instead. You're only interested in looking up whether a number is in that collection, so make it a set from the start:

```
npnumeros = set()
# ...
for i in range( 2, int( sqrt( num ) ) + 1 ):
    for j in range( i, int( num / i ) + 1 ):
        np = i * j
        npnumeros.add( np )

# npnumeros = list( set( npnumeros ) )  # Remove this line, it's no longer needed

for e in tnumeros:
    if ( e in npnumeros ):
        continue
    else:
        pnumeros.append( e )
```

The reason your code is slow is that looking up numbers in a list is O(N) time, and doing that inside an O(N) loop is O(N^2) time. But looking up numbers in a set is O(1) time, so you'll have O(N) time inside that loop. Going from O(N^2) to O(N) is going to represent a HUGE difference in processing speed.

If you don't understand the O(N) notation I used, [Google "Big O notation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=big+o+notation) to read more about it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understood what you said about O(N) and these things but you were right to said that making npnumeros as a set instead of a list, my program would run faster. It takes a little but it runs now.

Comment: @cotuex - Basically, big-O notation is a way of saying "how long this program takes depends on how large its input data is". O(N) means "the program's runtime is proportional to N, the number of items in the input data". O(N^2) means the runtime is proportional to the *square* of N. So if an O(N) program takes 2 seconds to run with 2 inputs, it will take 7 seconds to run with 7 inputs, and 25 seconds to run with 25 inputs. If an O(N^2) program takes 4 seconds to run with 2 inputs, it will take 49 seconds to run with 7 inputs, and 625 seconds (10 minutes) to run with 25 inputs.

Comment: Now: Looking up items in a list is an O(N) operation, because Python does a loop through the list, comparing each item in the list one at a time. That takes an amount of time proportional to N, the number of items in the list. And if you're ALSO running that call inside a loop which has roughly N items, then the time taken is proportional to N*N, or N squared. That's bad: your N is quite large in this case, about 100,000, so N^2 is HUGE. Getting the runtime from "proportional to N squared" down to "proportional to N" makes a HUGE difference.

Comment: And the thing about Python sets is, looking up an item in the set takes *constant* time (which is written as O(1) in big-O notation). No matter whether the set has just a couple items in it, or has 100,000 items in it, looking up "does the set contain this item, or not?" will take the same amount of time. Doing that inside the loop takes time proportional to N*1, instead of N*N. So when N = 100,000 the loop runs in just 100,000 time units (where one "time unit" is probably a few microseconds), instead of 100,000^2 = 10 *billion* time units.

Comment: Your explication was perfect and now I could understand what were you meaning whit O(N). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a severly truncated answer, due to the fact this question should probably be moved to CR.

One quick speed up is simply leaving npnumeros as a set instead of a list. What that means is that the later computation `if ( e in npnumeros ):` will happen sigifcantly faster.

The modified code:

```
from math import *

def primos(num):
    num2     = num + 1
    tnumeros = []                      # tnumeros  = every number from 2 to num
    npnumeros= []                      # npnumeros = every number that is no prime
    pnumeros = []                      # pnumeros  = every prime number

    for a in range( 2, num2 ):
        tnumeros.append( a )

    for i in range( 2, int( sqrt( num ) ) + 1 ):
        for j in range( i, int( num / i ) + 1 ):
            np = i * j
            npnumeros.append( np )

    npnumeros = set( npnumeros )

    for e in tnumeros:
        if ( e in npnumeros ):
            continue
        else:
            pnumeros.append( e )

    return ( str( "".join( str( pnumeros ) ) ) )

print( primos( 100000 ) )
```

runs ~60 times faster.

Comment: Thank, you. What you have said is what rmunn said and you were right but please, next time recheck when you write a code because as you write it, with text that I don't know if it is code or simply text, and as I know it's my code I can't perfectly compare my old code with yours. But thank you anyway.